# Caesar cipher won't work in C

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am trying to create a Caesar cipher, so I declared a function that pushes every character 13 times. And then another function that takes a string and then encrypts or decrypts it, I did that with the for loop.
But the problem is that when I run the programm this is what comes out:

```
Original: This is the Original text
encrypted: QnÇ vÇü qre Bevtvanyüràü
decrypted: DaÇ âÇü der Orâüânaåüeàü
```

Does anybody have an idea, what might be causing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int shift = 13;

char shiftchar(char ch){
    if( ((ch > 64) && (ch< 91)) || ((ch > 96) && (ch < 123)) ){
        ch = ch + shift;
        if(ch > 90 && ch < 104){
            ch = ch - 90 +64;
        }
        else if(ch > 122 && ch < 136){
            ch = ch -122 +96;
        }
    }
    else{
    ch = ch;
    }
}

void cipher (char str[]){

    for( int i = 0; str[i] != 0; ++i){
        str[i] = shiftchar(str[i]);
    }
}

int main(void){

    char str[25] = "This is the original text";

    printf("Original: ");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    cipher(str);
    printf("encrypted: ");
    printf("%s\n", str);

    cipher(str);
    printf("decrypted: ");
    printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: The use of the numbers `64`, `91`, `96`, `123`, `90`, `104`, `122`, `136` are red flags.  Use character constants `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'a'`, `'z'` and adjust the use of `>` to `>=` and `<` to `<=` as appropriate.  The `isupper()` and `islower()` functions from `<ctype.h>` could be helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had two simple bugs with your code. First, a variable of type `char` takes up `8 bits` in memory with values ranging form `-128` to `127`. In some cases, your ciphered character might end up with a value greater than `127` so you need to use an `unsigned char` as the data type which takes values ranging from `0` to `255` instead.

So, your function declaration should look like : `char shiftchar(unsigned char ch);`

There is also no need for this line of code : `ch = ch;` and you also didn't return the resulting ciphered character from your function.

The final function should look like this :

```
char shiftchar(unsigned char ch){
    if( ((ch > 64) && (ch< 91)) || ((ch > 96) && (ch < 123)) ){
        ch = ch + shift;
        if(ch > 90 && ch < 104){
            ch = ch - 90 +64;
        }
        else if(ch > 122 && ch < 136){
            ch = ch -122 +96;
        }
    }
    return ch;
}
```

Your code will be functioning as desired by now but to have everything perfectly done we need to modify the size of your character array. You set the size of the array `char str[]` in `main` to `25`.

**Never forget the invisible `NULL` terminating character at the end of any string literal you use to initialize your array.**

The array declaration should be : `char str[26] = "This is the original text";`, you can also avoid the headache of forgetting the `\0`, you can do this instead : `char str[] = "This is the original text";`thus leaving the job to the compiler to determine the size of the array ;)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have forgotten that a `char` string is really called ***null-terminated*** byte string. The *null-terminator* is extremely important, since that's what all standard functions are looking for to know when and where the string ends.

You array `str` is to small to fit the terminator. Make it an array of 26 elements instead. Or don't specify a size explicitly and let the compiler set it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and, besides the `unsigned` issue, you are missing the `return` statement in the `shiftchar` function.

```
char shiftchar(unsigned char ch){
    if( ((ch > 64) && (ch< 91)) || ((ch > 96) && (ch < 123)) ){
        ch = ch + shift;
        if(ch > 90 && ch < 104){
            ch = ch - 90 +64;
        }
        else if(ch > 122 && ch < 136){
            ch = ch -122 +96;
        }
    }
    else{
    ch = ch;
    }
    return ch;
}
```

Comment: Some compilers will also return an error message for doing this : `ch = ch;`. There's utterly no need for it.

Comment: Sure. I should have removed it.